# What is the difference between a homepage link with or without a trailing slash?

Tags: url, trailing-slash

What is the difference between these two URLs:

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com`

Should we always add the final `/` or avoid it? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no difference between them. (As [opposed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20093/why-treat-these-as-different-urls/20097#20097) to not putting a slash on links into a directory, for example.) I don't think I've ever seen anything saying that you should or shouldn't use a trailing slash for absolute URLs, though being consistent in your own behavior is generally not a bad idea either.

Comment: The server internally adds it for the request, at one time you got quicker response by having it there ahead of time. Fast hardware now, meh.

Comment: @FiascoLabs: actually, per the HTTP spec adding the trailing slash for the root domain should be performed by the _client_, not the server. In other words, your browser usually adds its before requesting the page from the server.

Answer (score 6):

> One of the most wasteful redirects happens frequently and web developers are generally not aware of it. It occurs when a trailing slash (/) is missing from a URL that should otherwise have one. For example, going to "http://astrology.yahoo.com/astrology" results in a 301 response containing a redirect to "http://astrology.yahoo.com/astrology/" (notice the added trailing slash). This is fixed in Apache by using Alias or mod_rewrite, or the DirectorySlash directive if you're using Apache handlers.

from: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: But this does not apply to the question example

Comment: @leonbloy how does it not? as it shows not only a programmer issue, but given the site you frequent, could mean milliseconds of difference in page load time!

Comment: @SpYk3HH My comment (almost 3 years ago) referred to a previous version of the question, the posterior editions changed (I wonder why) the original meaning. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/20373/revisions

Comment: @leonbloy Unfortunately the edits did change the meaning significantly, so I rolled the question back to an earlier version.

Comment: @dan Well done, IMO. The accepted answer makes the proper distinction.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have identified that it doesn't seem to technically matter.

For me it is a matter of perception, if there is a trailing slash I'd expect something to be following it, a file name, an anchor.

I also think a lack of a trailing slash looks cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

It's a matter of Apache configuration (can't say about others)

Some Apaches can't handle site/path as site/path/index.file

Semantically both URL declare the same resource

Comment: It's nothing whatsoever to do with Apache. It's a browser issue.

Comment: @disgruntledgoat- Wrong statement! The DirectorySlash directive determines whether mod_dir should fixup URLs pointing to a directory or not.

Typically if a user requests a resource without a trailing slash, which points to a directory, mod_dir redirects him to the same resource, but with trailing slash for some good reasons...

Comment: the question is not about directories, it's about the root domain.

Comment: Apache is not the only webserver