# Difference between "/" at end of URL and without "/"

Tags: seo, google, htaccess, search-engine-indexing, 301-redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does it make a difference if your url ends in a trailing slash or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/does-it-make-a-difference-if-your-url-ends-in-a-trailing-slash-or-not)
>   [Why treat these as different URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20093/why-treat-these-as-different-urls)

I am doing a 301 redirect in my WP application using .htaccess and have mapped some of the URLs which have either been removed from the new domain or the URL structure has been changed. While doing I got a doubt

I have following URL structure in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^tag/waiting$  http://www.new.com/tag/relationships [R=301,L]
```

while checking this i found that at some places URL is like `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships` while at others its like `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships/`, while both refer to the same location but not sure 
if this will make any difference to SEO and search engines.
Please suggest if the way i am doing mapping is correct or do i need to modify it to handle both UR

Comment: And also [What is the difference between http://example.com/ and http://example.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/what-is-the-difference-between-http-example-com-and-http-example-com/20374#20374) for domain-only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically speaking `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships` and `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships/` are two different pages just like `http://www.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com/index.html` are two different pages even though they pull up the same page.

To make sure the search engines understand that `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships` and `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships/` are the same page use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). This tells the search engines that these pages are the same and which URL to use in their search results. It also makes sure all links to the canonical URL are credited to the main URL.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs but i am still not sure how can i do that since they will be redirected by the Apache (.htaccess file) to new URL

Comment: You put the canonical `<link>` tag in your web page. It doesn't involve htaccess at all.

Comment: Do you mean i should use one URL say `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships` in .htaccess file and its version with "/" in the <link> tag on new domain webpage or i need to add this canonical `<link>` on old domain.being new to this concept its a bit confusing for me

Comment: Keep your htaccess file as it is shown above. Then on `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships` put the canonical `<link>` tag for `http://www.new.com/tag/relationships/`.

Comment: Thanks John Conde♦ for quick help will need to see how this can be done in WordPress since the pages at WordPress will be generated dynamically.

Comment: @user702325, install WordPress SEO by Yoast then you can set them for any page as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Google Webmaster Tools Blog has a good article titled [To slash or not to slash](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html)