# What are proper process to disallow a site from google crawl

Tags: google, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have done google and get  the two solution for disallow  whole a site from

google crawl.

**1:**

```
  User-agent: *
    Disallow:
```

**2:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now can anyone tell me which proper code for **disallow whole site from Google crawl**

Comment: Of course the solution won't disallow just google crawl but instead *all* (robots-compliant) crawlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your whole site from being crawled, then **No. 2**:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This blocks every URL from being crawled. The URL-path following the `Disallow:` directive is a *prefix*. If the requested URL *starts* with this URL-path, it will be blocked. The minimum URL path you can have is `/` (your home page / document root) - you can't have an *empty* path (as suggested in comments). When you request `example.com`, the browser actually requests `example.com/` to make the request valid. See my other answer for [more information on the trailing slash](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/35646/1243).

`Disallow:` by itself (without a path) actually *allows* everything - the complete opposite!

Reference:
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: that mean if i use no 2 solution then  www.example.com  will crawl and www.example.com/  does not crawl. am i right?

Comment: No, `Disallow: /` blocks _everything_. Or rather, the minimum request you can make is `/`, you can't request _nothing_. When you request `example.com`, the browser actually requests `example.com/`.

Comment: thanks for you answer,Kindly update this comment to answer:

Comment: Vote +accept....

Comment: I updated my answer and added a link for more information with regards to the trailing slash.