# .htaccess Redirect if no sub string found in the URL

Tags: htaccess

Whenever user comes in `example.com` how to redirect them to `example.com/home`

**Note:** 
The current routing/URL paths should work after adding this condition/rule

For example:

- `example.com/about-us` -> no redirect
- `example.com/contact` -> no redirect
- `example.com/admin` -> no redirect
- `example.com` or `example.com/` -> Need to redirect to `example.com/home`

How can be this done with `.htaccess` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to redirect a specific URL; the document root. At the top of your `.htaccess` file try the following mod_rewrite directive:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /home [R=302,L]
```

I assume you are already using mod_rewrite, as otherwise you are unlikely to have URLs like `/about-us` and `/contact`, etc.

Note the above is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

---

> `example.com` or `example.com/` -> Need to redirect to `example.com/home`

These are the same URL. There is *always* a trailing slash after the hostname, even if you don't see it in the browser's address bar. See the following question for reference:

- [Is trailing slash automagically added on click of home page URL in browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser)