# Should redirects to the home page including a trailing slash?

Tags: seo, redirects, trailing-slash

The website URL is `http://example.com` but some pages have been redirected to `http://example.com/`, the version of the URL with the trailing slash. Should I change all redirects to the non-trailing-slash URL?

Comment: Are you talking about the trailing slash on the home page (the root of the domain) without any extra path?   The situation for that (`http://example.com` vs `http://example.com/`) is different than for a directory (`/folder` vs `/folder/`).

Comment: Actually it is the homepage not subfolder

Comment: Launch some developer tools inside your browser, and inspect the HTTP request being done. Even if you type just a name or an "URL" like `http://example.com` you will see that your browser sends in fact a `GET /` request, so at least a `/` is mandatory to say "root".

Comment: Yes, as Patrick suggests, don't just look at the "beautified" URL in the browser's address bar. Browser's notoriously "beautify" the public URL seen in the browser - more so these days than they ever did. See also: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Comment: not really matter for redirect in q if done corecct but redirect technique also matters, for example doing apache `redirect` without trailing slash will most probably fail if original request came with path like example.com/foo. it will redirect to invalid example.comfoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Homepage: Google has stated that the homepage doesnt really matter if there is or isnt a trailing slash.
- Directory: directories must have a trailing slash in the end.
- File/Page: an html page or an file shouldn't have a trailing slash.

Comment: It's not just Google.  When it comes to the home page, the HTTP spec states that there is no difference between having a trailing slash and not having one.   Whether or not the slash shows in the URL, the HTTP request **must** include the slash.

Comment: Note example.com/index.php are the same as example.com/index.php/something at least for apache. You can process this trailing uri in index.php, making possible to use different urls with same script without mod_rewrite