# How to set base and canonical tags properly?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, meta-tags

I found some urls indexed by google wich doesn't have in my site, so I tought its because of the canonical tag and base tag.

I need an explanition for `base` tag and `canonical` tags.

Here are my questions:

> 1.Do I have to use both tags in pages or choose one of them?
>
> 2.If I set my baseurl tag to http://example.com/ then canonical url will show another url in sub pages like so:
>   http://example.com/sub-page/. so! Does it affect to seo? And if it
>   does! how to solve it?
>
> 3.If my domain is redirected to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) without a slash at the end in htaccess and baseurl tag is with a slash at the end of
>   the url, will it affect to seo urls?

Comment: This is unfortunately too broad and unclear. Please edit the question to reduce to one specific issue and it will be added to the review queue for consideration to be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I am assuming you mean the `base` tag. It is unrelated to the `canonical` tag. You can use neither, one, or both on your pages with no issue.
2. Whatever you set as the `base` tag will never affect the `canonical` tag, because the `canonical` tag must always be an absolute URL and the `base` tag only affects relative URLs.
3. No. A home page without a slash is equivalent to one with a slash. You should always write your home page with a trailing slash if possible [because it is the canonical version](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/canonical-url-for-a-home-page-and-trailing-slashes#comment50994_33074), but it doesn't matter much in practice.

Comment: Thank you @Maximillian Laumeister I was confused about both tags.