# Should I include a trailing slash for my <xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="URL" hreflang="en-US"/> URLs?

Tags: seo, sitemap, internationalization, hreflang, trailing-slash

I'm implementing `hreflang` on my web app.

Google does not mention anything on https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

But they use it (trailing slashes) on their own Sitemap.

https://www.google.com/sitemap_search.xml

[image]

Does it make any difference at all?

Comment: Are you asking about the trailing slash on the URL or on the link tag?

Comment: On the URL. Both on `<loc>URL</loc>` and on `<xhtml:link href="URL" ... />`.

Comment: So `<loc>http://example.com/</loc>` vs `<loc>http://example.com/</loc>` and `<xhtml:link href="http://example.com/" ... />` vs `<xhtml:link href="http://example.com" ... />`?   Are you asking only about your home page or about deep links as well.  Do you need advice about `http://example.com/page` vs `http://example.com/page/`?

Comment: Yes. Both cases. Home and also subfolders. Would like to know if it makes any difference having the trailing slash or not.

Comment: For general advice about trailing slashes see [What is the difference between a homepage link with or without a trailing slash?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/what-is-the-difference-between-a-homepage-link-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash) and [Does it make a difference if your URL path ends in a trailing slash or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/does-it-make-a-difference-if-your-url-path-ends-in-a-trailing-slash-or-not).   An answer here could give you direction about how to choose what to put in your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller . Will check those out!

Answer (score 1):

XML, which XHTML is, requires self-closing tags to have a closing slash.

In a URI, a trailing slash indicates a directory resource.

In a URI, no trailing slash indicates a resource; such as a file.

On a top level domain, such as `https://example.net/`, browsers will drop the closing slash but I can't think of the details at the moment.