# Is Googlebot case sensitive? Should I use a 301 redirect to choose a preferred URL case?

Tags: seo, google, url, googlebot, case-sensitive

The Googlebot reports the following:

Pages with duplicate meta descriptions

1. `/Default.aspx?p=2`
2. `/default.aspx?p=2`

Should I use a 301 redirect from `Default` to `default` or vice versa?

Is Googlebot case sensitive?

Comment: Case-sensitivity is a [server matter](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20093/why-treat-these-as-different-urls/20097), by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both pages pull up the same content either do a 301 redirect from one to the other or use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).